# Dragging over a Textbox loses drag focus - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement an auto-scroll feature in WPF when dragging and dropping items in a RadTreeView (telerik), but I come up against a problem when there is a TextBox in one of the TreeViewItem cells.

I've attached a screenshot to try and give an idea.

[image]

Now, in order to drag and drop rows, you select the cell on the left(Number column) and drag up or down, and if the mouse stays in that first column, then the auto-scroll works really well.  However, if while dragging, you move the move over to the next column with the text (Activity column), the auto-scroll fails to work due to the text being an active textbox. If I set all the textboxes to inactive, it works perfectly.

So, my question is this - is there anyway of setting the textbox to inactive when dragging over, and then reactivating it once you have passed over it?  (or if there is a better way to accomplish the result I'm looking for, what could I try?)

It could be that the text box has it's own Drag and Drop events that are firing and essentially hijacking the main drag event while the mouse is over the textbox, but my lack of experience with WPF could be the reason I can't find them!

Here is what I've tried so far:

- Set all TextBoxes to inactive on `drag_start` event, then reset on `drag_ended` event.  (this was buggy, because the drag_ended event wasn't always fired, leaving the TextBoxes inactive)
- Set all TextBoxes to Readonly (didn't work as drag lost focus in same way as when TextBox is active)
- I've tried to stop drag/drop on the TextBox on Mouse Over.

Any advice appreciated here - being driven demented by this final issue!

Thanks

Comment: Does the MouseUp event fire when the drag has ended. If so, if I recall correctly, there is a boolean property associated with a drag operation currently happening (or not). Also, have you looked at the 'Preview' versions of these events, especially the drag_ended?

Comment: Hi ouflak - No the MouseUp event doesn't fire with the drag drop, even if the drag_ended event fires.  The PreviewDragEnded is the same as DragEnded in that if I release the button without having a DropPosition, it doesn't fire, and so leaves all textboxes inactive

Comment: Just throwing some guesses out there: Try setting e.Handled = true in the drag_start handler. Likewise, hook up to the PreviewMouseOver of the textboxes and mark e.Handled at true. That might be enough to stop whatever event is bubbling through to cause the focus to shift.